# Move Vue form input validation in component into a method

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue componenet for my input field. I have added some validation that makes sure only numbers are added. I added this on the oninput.

I'd like to move this to a method so I can add more checks (eg. if Type !== number)

This works well, but with the validation inline:

```
        <input
            v-bind="$attrs"
            v-on="{
                ...$listeners,
                input: event => $emit('input', event.target.value)
            }"
            oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"
        />
```

This is how I would like it (but current the validation is not working):

```
        <input
            v-bind="$attrs"
            v-on="{
                ...$listeners,
                input: event => handleInput(event.target.value)
            }"
        />

methods: {
   handleInput(value) {
        console.log(value);
        // 1st emit
        this.$emit("input", value);

        // 2nd Validate -- Not working...
        this.value = Math.abs(this.value);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I get this.value = Math.abs(this.value); to feed back into the input?

UPDATE

Thanks to a helpful comment I made some progress. The below code works for the first character but not for ongoing characters.

If numbers are typed, then validation passes true and input emitted.
If 1 character (eg. a) is typed then we emit the number 0. If a second character is inputted then the char is emitted (eg. press b and now the input is 0b)

I can see the this.$emit("input", 0) is triggered, so not sure why char emitted.

```
    methods: {
    validateInput(value) {
        // if it type isnt set as a number then leave
        if (this.type != "number") {
            return true;
        }
        // check if value a number
        if (Math.abs(value)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    },
    handleInput(value) {
        if (this.validateInput(value)) {
            this.$emit("input", value);
        } else {
            this.$emit("input", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'validation', as this generally would mean a comparison that returns true or false, but here you're assigning a new value. ---
If you want to check if the input value is absolute before emitting, you can wrap your `$emit` in an if statement. If you want to automatically set the value to be absolute, consider binding a computed value to the input's `:value` property. ---
In any case, you'd run validations BEFORE emitting an event.

Comment: Validation sounds like incorrect word for the process. I want to check if value is an integer and disallow characters from being input. Really helpful with the idea that I should 'validate' before. I'll make method into a boolean check and then wrap on $emit i think. Cheers

Comment: HTML5 has `<input type="number">` which would do that automatically for you, as well as trigger a number input on mobile devices. Unless you need to support really old versions of IE, you could probably use that and save yourself from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @Excalibaard but unfortunately that only works on submit. Because I am using the reactive nature of Vue I need to be strict in only allowing numbers being inputted and the HTML5 type does extend that far (annoyingly!).

Comment: I think HTML5 input type="number" doesn't allow characters to be entered, but I could be wrong there. You made a mistake in your validator function, if it returns true after the first validation passes, how would it ever check for the second validation? I'll write up an answer that would work for your situation, but there are also libraries out there like https://vuelidate.js.org/ for more advanced validation handling once you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a value before emitting the input event, you could do it like this:

```
 methods: {
    validateInput(value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') { return false; } // check if it's not a string
        if (value !== Math.abs(value)) { return false; } // check if value is positive
        return true
    }
    handleInput(value) {
        if (this.validateInput(value)) { this.$emit("input", value); }
        this.$emit("input") // if value is not a valid input, you may want to do nothing, or emit merely that the event happened.
    }
}
```

A better way of doing a custom input would be to use the `value` prop of an input, and bind it to a dynamic property in your component, for example by using `v-model="value"`. Fun fact: `v-model` has a modifier `v-model.number` which would do exactly what you need.

The only caveat is that you can't directly modify props, so you'd need to use a **computed property** as a way to automatically handle the 'getting and setting' of your form's value.

```
// CustomInput.vue

<template>
  <input v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" v-model.number="localValue" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    }
  }
  computed: {
    localValue: {
      get() { return this.value; }
      set(newVal) { this.$emit('input', newVal); }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You don't need to make a custom component for this case. You could simply use `v-model.number` in the parent and it would work. Once your inputs get more complex, you want to modify the set method a bit to `set(newVal) { if (this.validateInput(newVal)) {this.$emit('input', newVal);} }`, defining your own 'validateInput' method.

If you find you're writing a lot of different validations for different use cases, look into libraries like [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) and [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/)